# Run django app through ip address (ALLOWED_HOST)

Tags: python, django

im stuck in hosting my Django app. Can you guys help me to sort it out.

**settings.py**

```
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['http://127.0.0.1:8000', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1', '192.168.1.190',]
```

**and my ifconfig is**

[image]

I tried this

```
python manage.py runserver 0:8000
python manage.py runserver 192.168.1.190:8000
```

I got the following result in my browser

```
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
```

Correct me if I am wrong. Thanks in advance. Have a great day.

Comment: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 and browse your ip:8000 eg 192.168.1.190:8000

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:port
Eg.
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
and browse ip:port
Eg. 192.168.1.190:8000
```

If you should use same network to open in another computer.

Comment: thanks for the reply. i already try this method(192.168.1.190:8000) but still im getting the same error. i disable the firewall in my ubuntu machine but it still shows your site cant be reached.